# Accessing new features after upgrading a license

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, dashboard

I've been tasked with getting a dashboard going using Excel Web Access Web Parts.  These weren't listed as an option, however, under the Business Data category.  I accessed this menu through the series of clicks Edit Page->Insert->Web Part->Business Data, if that's in any way relevant.  I assumed this was due to being under a license that didn't support the feature, and so I was reassigned to use a trial Enterprise Plan E3.

Excel Web Access still isn't displayed under the Business Data category.  I thought I may need to activate the new features somehow, but either I don't have access to do so or I'm on the wrong track with that thought.  The entire team is new to SharePoint, and not even the admin I've spoken with is knowledgeable enough to be of help here.  My intuition tells me the admin may need to activate the feature, but he's absurdly busy with other things and I'd rather not bug him unless I was sure I needed him.  So my question really is: what steps do I need to take to begin working with Excel Web Access Web Parts?

Thanks in advance!

Relevant Screen Captures:

**Items in the Business Data category**
[image: Business Data]

**Site Feature Activated**
[image: Enterprise Features Activated]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is Excel Web parts are available with [Office 365 Enterprise E3](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn788955) Plan. Once you have Enterprise features turned on you should be able to add the Excel Web Access Webpart fine. See [this](http://itfreesupport.com/2014/12/in-sharepoint-online-office-365-under-business-data-section-excel-web-part-is-not-available/) article for details.

You might be also interested in this [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198236.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm under an E3 trial license and the first article you linked to I actually found in my own googling.  The Enterprise features have been turned on, but unfortunately still no luck.  As to the technet article, do you have to have a BI Center site for excel web access web parts to function?

Comment: BI center is not necessary. May be try disabling the Site collection 'Enterprise feature' and re-enable to see if that adds the webpart? Can you add a screenshot what you see under the 'business data' group?

Comment: I added a couple screenshots.  Thanks so much for your help.